# Xtext terminal overlapping

Tags: editor, grammar, xtext

I am new to Xtext and I am facing following issue:
Under every "error id :" line i can expect every printable character with spaces/tabs between. My language is indent-based so this "terminal" cannot start with space character.

Edit/:
Example code for this language would look like this:

```
package somepkg:    
    error UNKNOWN:
        Unknown error.
    error ZERO_DIVISION:
        Do not divide by zero you {0} donkey!.
```

Closest i get to this language specification is this:

```
grammar com.example.lang.ermsglang.Ermsglang with org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.Xbase hidden(WS)

import "http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore" as ecore
generate ermsglang "http://www.example.com/lang/ermsglang/Ermsglang"

Model:
    {Model}
    'package' name=ENAME ':'
    (BEGIN
        (expressions+=Error)+
    END)?
;

Error:
    {Error}
    'error' name=ENAME ':'
    (BEGIN
        (expressions+=Anything)+
    END)?
;

Anything:
    (ENAME|EMSG|INT)
;

//Terminals must be disjunctive
terminal ENAME:
    ('_'|'A'..'Z') ('_'|'A'..'Z')*
;

terminal EMSG:
    ('!'..'/'|':'..'@'|'['..'~')+
;

terminal SL_COMMENT: 
    '#' !('\n'|'\r')* ('\r'? '\n')?
;

// The following synthetic tokens are used for the indentation-aware blocks
terminal BEGIN: 'synthetic:BEGIN';  // increase indentation
terminal END: 'synthetic:END';      // decrease indentation
```

But still, this allows either ENAME or EMSG or INT terminals, so you cant mix for example numbers with characters. Problem is terminals have to be disjunctive so if i modify rule "ANYTHING" like this:

```
terminal ANYTHING:
    (ENAME|EMSG|INT)+
;
```

or

```
Anything:
   (ENAME|EMSG|INT)+
;
```

will be a problem with lexer/parser which cannot determine which terminal is which. How to deal with this situation? Thanks.

//Edit: Thank to Christian for working example, there is still one problem with SL_COMMENT, in this example second error keyword is highlighted with message

> missing RULE_END at 'error'

```
package A : 
    error B :
        a
        #bopsa Akfkfndsfio
    error A_C_S :
        :aasdasdasd
```

Comment: why inherit from xbase or any other terminal. lexing is context free thus you need to unambigous on lexer level. if you inherit from xbase you inherit a lot of terminal rules

Comment: @ChristianDietrich because without it , the special terminals :
`terminal BEGIN: 'synthetic:BEGIN';  // increase indentation`
`terminal END: 'synthetic:END';      // decrease indentation`

do not work. Lexing is context-free but the language itself is not. It depends on context of indentation depth.

Comment: can you file a bug for that. if you inherit then you have to add ID, INT etc to your AllStuff Rule as well or override them to something that will never occurr in the models e.g. ```'@@@@@@@@@@@@INT@@@@@@@@@@@'```

Comment: did you add a ws rule when not inheriting from xbase/terminals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the follwoing grammar works for me

```
grammar org.xtext.example.mydsl3.MyDsl hidden (WS, SL_COMMENT)

generate myDsl "http://www.xtext.org/example/mydsl3/MyDsl"

import "http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore" as ecore

Model:
    {Model}
    'package' name=ENAME ':'
    (BEGIN
        (expressions+=Error)+
    END)?
;

Error:
    {Error}
    'error' name=ENAME ':'
    (BEGIN
        (expressions+=Anything)+
    END)?
;

Anything:
    (ENAME|EMSG|INT|':')
;

//Terminals must be disjunctive
terminal ENAME:
    ('_'|'A'..'Z'|'a'..'z') ('_'|'A'..'Z'|'a'..'z')*
;
terminal INT returns ecore::EInt: ('0'..'9')+;

terminal EMSG:
    ('!'..'/'|';'..'@'|'['..'~')+
;

terminal SL_COMMENT: 
    '#' !('\n'|'\r')* ('\r'? '\n')?
;



// The following synthetic tokens are used for the indentation-aware blocks
terminal BEGIN: 'synthetic:BEGIN';  // increase indentation
terminal END: 'synthetic:END';      // decrease indentation

terminal WS         : (' '|'\t'|'\r'|'\n')+;

terminal ANY_OTHER: .;
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, looks like it works without xbase then. I managed to implement it according to your grammar example. I still investigate one problem tho (that is even in this example) and that is SL_COMMENT which causes error. See edits for example.

Comment: Okay solved it, problem was (in this example) in character range 
`'!'..'/'` which included '#' character and this was conflicting with SL_comment terminal definition of course.